# My list.view builder is not projecting images to the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, shopping-cart, consumer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:groceryapp/model/cart_model2.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class CartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CartItems(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.grey[800],
          ),
        ),
        body: Consumer<CartItems>(
          builder: (context, dataProvider, child) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // Let's order fresh items for you
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Ödeme",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 36,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // list view of cart
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: dataProvider.cartItems.length,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                dataProvider.cartItems[index]["name"],
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                dataProvider.cartItems[index]["price"] + '₺' ,
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                              ),
                              trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                                  onPressed: () =>
                                      Provider.of<CartItems>(context, listen: false)
                                      .cartListeSil(index),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // total amount + pay now

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Ödenecek Tutar',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[200]),
                            ),

                            const SizedBox(height: 8),
                            // total price
                            Text(
                              '\₺${dataProvider.ToplamHesapla()}',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        // pay now
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                                context, "/paymentpage");
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.green.shade200),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                            ),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                            child: const Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Ödeme',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                                  size: 16,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I'm trying to make my company's mobile app.When the user adds the product to the cart, he adds the data to the "cartItems" list in "map" format. now i want to display the elements of the list in my cart.The "cartItems" list keeps the data in "map" form. I'm trying to dynamically mirror the data in the list with "list.view". The problem is that it is not reflected on the screen whether there is an element in the list or not. I can show other code details if you want. How do I solve the problem?**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../components/grocery_item_tile.dart';
import '../components/urun_list.dart';
import '../model/cart_model2.dart';
import 'cart_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  CartItems _cartItems = CartItems();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference damacanaRef = _firestore.collection("damacana");
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: damacanaRef.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext contex, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot) {
        ///   List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocSnap = asyncSnapshot.data.docs;
        ///   List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocSnap = asyncSnapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) => doc as DocumentSnapshot).toList();
        if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text("Error: ${asyncSnapshot.error}"));
        } else {
          if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
            //List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocSnap = asyncSnapshot.data.docs;
            return ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => _cartItems,
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  elevation: 0,
                  leading: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Istanbul, Cekmekoy ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                    ),
                  ),
                  centerTitle: false,
                  actions: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24.0),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[200],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/cartpage"),
                  child: const Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
                      ),
                      Text("Sepet")
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                body: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 48),

// good morning bro
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                      child: Text('Merhaba,'),
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(height: 4),

// Let's order fresh items for you
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Sizin için ürünlerimiz",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 36,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(height: 24),

                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                      child: Divider(),
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(height: 24),

// categories -> horizontal listview
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0, left: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            "${_firestore.collection("damacana").id}",
                            style: const TextStyle(
//fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0, left: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            "${_firestore.collection("PetSu").id}",
                            style: const TextStyle(
//fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0, left: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            "${_firestore.collection("Meşrubatlar").id}",
                            style: const TextStyle(
//fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

// recent orders -> show last 3
                    Expanded(
                      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: _firestore.collection('damacana').snapshots(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
                            // Hata durumunu burada işleyin
                            return Center(
                                child: Text("Hata: ${asyncSnapshot.error}"));
                          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            List<Widget> widgets = [];
                            snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
                              String name = doc['name'];
                              String price = doc['price'];
                              String size = doc['size'];

                              widgets.add(urun_info(
                                  name: name,
                                  price: price,
                                  size: size,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                  _cartItems.cartListeEkle({
                                    "name": name,
                                    "price": price,
                                    "size": size,

                                  });
                                  print(_cartItems.cartItems);
                                },

                                  ));
                              print(CartItems().cartItems);
                            });

                            return GridView.count(
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.5,
                              children: widgets,
                            );
                          } else {
                            return CircularProgressIndicator();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**AND MY CLASS**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CartItems extends ChangeNotifier{

   List<Map<String, dynamic>> cartItems = [];

   void cartListeEkle(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot) {
    cartItems.add(snapshot);
    notifyListeners();
  }

   void cartListeSil(int index) {
     cartItems.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String ToplamHesapla(){
    double toplamHesap = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< cartItems.length; i++){
      toplamHesap += double.parse(cartItems[i]["price"]);
    }
    return toplamHesap.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }

}
```

Comment: how about value.cartItems ? is it correct that there is data in it?

Comment: In the current version of my question, I have shown how I pass data to the list. When I print with "Print", my list shows data, but on my other page the same list is empty. Why is the data entered in the list lost when the button is pressed?